# unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'

Tags: r

Can somebody please explain what's going on here?

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

```
 [,1] [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5] [,6]  [,7]   [,8]  [,9]   [,10]  [,11] 
[1,] 0    -105.2 -97.49 -129.5 150  -62.5 -55.33 84.88 -15.15 32.69  -58.34
[2,] 1    -118.6 -107.4 -92.12 -10  -125  35     70.47 84.67  -113.5 12.99 
     [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]  [,17]  [,18]  [,19]  [,20]  [,21]   [,22] 
[1,] 144.4 -49.7 0.494 122.1 106.4  -98.28 58.86  133    223.86 -269.99 327.23
[2,] 55    35.61 127.3 78.7  -60.01 44.7   -54.83 -11.41 17.74  -1.37   52.26 
     [,23]  [,24]  [,25]   [,26]  [,27]  [,28]   [,29]  [,30]   
[1,] 199.52 260.96 -137.21 37.11  238.15 -240.45 32.74  1320.327
[2,] 171.09 199.15 256.82  -27.02 48.12  -212.13 126.98 1098.386
```

Error in order(evaluated[, ncol(evaluated)]) : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'

the matrix above is what print(evaluated) returns.

str(evaluated) returns

```
List of 60
 $ : int 0
 $ : int 1
 $ : num -105
 $ : num -119
```

...

```
 $ : num 32.7
 $ : num 127
 $ : num 1320
 $ : num 1098
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 30
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:30] "" "" "" "" ...
```

Comment: Include the result of `str(evaluated)`

Comment: Well there's your problem.  You have a `list`, but you want a `matrix` or `data.frame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this into the proper object.  Here is an example as a `matrix`:

```
xx <- scan(
file=textConnection(" 0 -105.2 -97.49 -129.5 150  -62.5 -55.33 84.88 -15.15 32.69  -58.34
 144.4 -49.7 0.494 122.1 106.4  -98.28 58.86  133    223.86 -269.99 327.23
 199.52 260.96 -137.21 37.11  238.15 -240.45 32.74  1320.327
 1 -118.6 -107.4 -92.12 -10  -125  35     70.47 84.67  -113.5 12.99 
 55    35.61 127.3 78.7  -60.01 44.7   -54.83 -11.41 17.74  -1.37   52.26 
 171.09 199.15 256.82  -27.02 48.12  -212.13 126.98 1098.386"
))

evaluated <- matrix(xx, byrow=TRUE, nrow=2)

order(evaluated[, ncol(evaluated)])
## [1] 2 1
```